# Specify where to install 'tests_require' dependencies of a distribute/setuptools package

Tags: python, testing, setuptools, distribute

When I run `python setup.py test` the dependencies listed in `tests_require` in setup.py are downloaded to the current directory. When I run `python setup.py install`, the dependencies listed in `requires` are instead installed to `site-packages`.

How can I have those `tests_require` dependencies instead installed in `site-packages`?

Comment: setuptools `tests_require` is [deprecated since 41.5.0](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) (October 2019). We are now at 50.3.0.

Comment: Hello @MartinThoma is there an alternative to specify requirements needed for dev/test but not plain usage?

Comment: That would be something like `extras_require={'test': ['pytest']}` in setup.py I think.

Comment: @MartinThoma the [release notes](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v41-5-0) make no mention of that

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You cannot specify where the test requirements are installed. The whole point of the tests_require parameter is to specify dependencies that are not required for the installation of the package but only for running the tests (as you can imagine many consumers might want to install the package but not run the tests). If you want the test requirements to be included during installation, I would include them in the install_requires parameter. For example:

```
test_requirements = ['pytest>=2.1', 'dingus']
setup(
    # ...
    tests_require = test_requirements,
    install_requires = [
        # ... (your usual install requirements)
    ] + test_requirements,
)
```

As far as I know, there's no parameter you can pass to force this behavior without changing the setup script.

Comment: I found [this article](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2009/12/17/managing-dependencies.html) which describes using 'extras' for a similar purpose.

Comment: I no longer recommend this technique. If tests are required for installation (whether or not they're required for tests), just put them in `install_requires`, and don't bother adding them to `tests_require`.

Answer (score 29):

You can use a virtualenv to avoid this and install the extra packages to their default locations, inside lib/pythonX/site-packages. First, you should define your testing requirements as extras, in setup.py:

```
setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=[
        # ... (your usual install requirements)
    ],
    extras_require={
        'testing': [
            # ... (your test requirements)
        ]
    },
)
```

Then install your package with test requirements like this:

```
pip install -e ".[testing]"
```

Comment: @Flimm It does not.  But you could pull the test packages into a list and reference the same list from `extras_require['test']` and `tests_require` like this answer does.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41398850/149428

Answer (score 18):

I am using *pip* to achieve something like that. Instead of adding *tests_requires* or *extras* to my setup.py I have created a [pip requirements file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files).

Example my **dev_requirements.txt** file:

```
pytest
webtest
```

Then to install it run:

```
$ pip install -r dev_requirements.txt
```

Comment: I believe `requirements-dev.txt` and `requirements-test.txt` are the more commonly used names for these files.

Comment: @phoenix the same can be said about `requirements/test.txt` and `requirements/prod.txt`